# Gatling Archive inside Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, gatling

I'm trying to include gatlingArchive() on my pipelines (already in prod). I tried to use the usual way of:

```
stages {
    stage("Run Gatling") {
        steps {
            ...
        }
        post {
            always {
                gatlingArchive()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But our jobs do not contain the 'pipeline' step. See below:

```
job("job-my-job") {
    label(...)
    parameters {...}
    wrappers {...}
    scm {...}
    steps {...}
    publishers {...}
    logRotator(-1, 90)
    configure {...}
}
```

I tried to include the post inside the steps section and wrap the steps inside a stage block, but the syntax failed. Is it possible to issue a post command for gatlingArchive() in this case, without a pipeline step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `publishers`. Here is the [documentation](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.archiveGatling)

```
 publishers {
        archiveGatling()
    }
```